# Splitting a CSV file by column name with regular expression, with the pandas library

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have been trying to automate splitting up data from a CSV file by column name using the pandas library with python rather than having to the process manually. With my current code I have been able to filter said data with a regular expression label into it's own data frame, however I am not sure how to take said filtered values and use them as indexes to split the main CSV file into smaller files.

Here is my code so far as you can tell I haven't really gotten far.

```py
import pandas as pd
        
def pivotChunk(path: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    labels = pd.read_csv(path,
                         encoding = 'unicode_escape',
                         engine ='python'
                         )
    filteredDF = labels.filter(regex='Total - ',axis=1)
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pivotChunk('2.1.csv')
```

And here is an example of the table I am working with:

| X | Total - example data | value1 | value2 | Total - data as examples | value3 | value4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| area 1 | 12 | 34 | 56 | 78 | 90 | 12 |
| area 2 | 21 | 43 | 65 | 87 | 09 | 21 |
| area 3 | 12 | 34 | 56 | 78 | 90 | 12 |
| area 4 | 53 | 27 | 41 | 96 | 80 | 53 |

And what I want to end up with.

Table 1:

| X | Total - example data | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| area 1 | 12 | 34 | 56 |
| area 2 | 21 | 43 | 65 |
| area 3 | 12 | 34 | 56 |
| area 4 | 53 | 27 | 41 |

Table 2:

| X | Total - data as examples | value3 | value4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| area 1 | 78 | 90 | 12 |
| area 2 | 87 | 09 | 21 |
| area 3 | 78 | 90 | 12 |
| area 4 | 96 | 80 | 53 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to split by groups starting with a "Total" column, you could use `groupby` on columns:

```
group = df.columns.str.startswith('Total').cumsum()
for k, d in df.set_index('X').groupby(group[1:], axis=1):
    print(d.reset_index()) # save instead in your case
```

Output:

```
        X  Total - example data  value1  value2
0  area 1                    12      34      56
1  area 2                    21      43      65
2  area 3                    12      34      56
3  area 4                    53      27      41
        X  Total - data as examples  value3  value4
0  area 1                        78      90      12
1  area 2                        87       9      21
2  area 3                        78      90      12
3  area 4                        96      80      53
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach is simpler. First I would find the index of the column, and then slice the dataframe according to it. here is the solution:

```
sep = df.columns.get_loc('Total - data as examples')
df1 = df.iloc[:,:sep]
df2 = df.iloc[:,sep:]

df1.to_csv(...)
df2.to_csv(...)
```